# Modified Transpose in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis, transpose

I am having a problem with my R dataframe. This is how it appears now:

```
 ID   Type   Count   Sum   Mean
 1      A      1      1     1
 1      B      2      10    5
```

I need to reduce the duplicate IDs to only one, then selectively tranpose the 'Type' and combine it with the other columns.

**Below is the result that I want:**

```
 ID   Count.A   Sum.A   Mean.A   Count.B   Sum.B   Mean.B
 1      1         1       1         2        10       5
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Type, values_from = Type:Mean)`

Comment: Confirmed working. thank you